# Filtering and reassigning pyspark dataframe in a loop

Tags: loops, apache-spark, dataframe, filter, pyspark

I'm trying to iterate through all the columns of a Pyspark data frame, calculating the IQR to filter the upper outliers, and reassigning the same dataframe. There are 200+ columns. This is working, but it goes slower and slower as it advances through the loop. I suspect the problem may be in the reassignment of the dataframe (dfBufferOutlier=dfBufferOutlier.filter(col(i)

```py
nameList=dfBuffer.schema.names[1:]    
dfBufferOutlier=dfBuffer
for i in nameList:
    cuenta=dfBufferOutlier.filter(col(i)>0).count()
    if cuenta>0:
        Q1, Q2, Q3 = dfBufferOutlier.filter(col(i)>0).approxQuantile(col=i,probabilities=[0.25,0.5,0.75],relativeError=0.005)
        IQR=(Q3-Q1)
        top_limit=Q3+1.5*IQR
        dfBufferOutlier=dfBufferOutlier.filter(col(i)<top_limit)
```

There sure must be another way to get this better, but can't figure out how.. any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to modify the procedure (arguably you should modify it anyway) a bit you can do everything in a single pass:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, when
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_

def iqr_filter(df, cols, relativeError=0.005):
    # Find quantiles
    quantiles = (df
        # Convert values <= 0 to NULL
        .select([when(col(c) > 0, col(c)).alias(c) for c in cols])
        .approxQuantile(cols, [0.25, 0.5, 0.75], relativeError))

    # Compute thresholds
    thresholds = [
        q3 + 1.5 * (q3 - q1) for q1, _, q3 in quantiles
    ]
    # Create SQL expression of form c1 < t1 AND c2 < t2 AND ... AND cn < tn
    expr  = reduce(and_, [col(c) < t for c, t in zip(cols, thresholds)])
    # Filter
    return df.where(expr)
```

Usage:

```
iqr_filter(dfBuffer, dfBuffer.schema.names[1:])
```

With very low relative error it might be still quite demanding job so I strongly suggest to relax it a bit, once number of columns grows.

Note that the result will be different from the one generated by your current approach:

- In your case each pass computes quantiles on non-increasing set of rows, therefore it depends on the order of columns.
- This computes quantiles once for all rows and doesn't depend on the order of columns.